# Macbook Webcam light turns on for a second when computer is waked

Tags: macos, webcam

Most of the time when I login or open the lid my macbook bro mid 2012, the webcam light turns on for about a second and then turns off. Is there anything I should be worried about like a virus using my webcam to take photos of me from my computer or something?

Comment: Possibly, but the webcam can also be used without the light on... As per Dutch government, put a sticker on it if you don't use it on purpose.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible you have installed, or someone else has installed, a system utility to capture the image from the iSight when opened. This is often something an anti-theft application might do, in order to track down the user of a stolen laptop.

One combination of utilities that can do this sort of thing is "[sleepwatcher](http://www.bernhard-baehr.de/)%20and%20imagesnap%20(http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/macosx/imagesnap/)"

You might check to see if there is a file at

```
/etc/rc.awake
```

or an invisible file in your home directory called

```
.sleep
```

If so, sleepwatcher is installed.

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me and I found it was because photobooth was open and trying to access the camera everytime it woke. I'd make sure it's closed.